# How to remove ICEpdf temporary files after application has finished working?

Tags: java, pdf, temporary-files, temporary, icepdf

I use ICEpdf library for PDF displaying at my desktop java application. Application adds annotations to PDF at runtime, but without changing original files — changes are displayed only during one 'session'. I recently discovered that application creates a lot of temporary files which consume quite a lot of disk space.

Method org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Document.setInputStream has the following code:

```
// Delete temp file on exit 
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```

So I suppose it has to remove temporary files after it used them, but it does not:

[image: ICE pdf temporary files]

How can I programmatically remove all files created by application on exit or make standard file removing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get temp folder path:

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))
```

To remove files:

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> paths = Files.newDirectoryStream(pathToDir, regex)){
        paths.forEach(path -> path.toFile().delete());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle io exception
    }
```

where regex is filename pattern. In your case: "IcePdf*"